# Test TensorFlow model with my own value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using  [this](http://gist.github.com/vinhkhuc/e53a70f9e5c3f55852b0) TensorFlow example to train some data I downloaded. But I wanted to be able to input new data (in a list) and see how the net would classify it.

How can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you want is simply add after the loop (i.e. after training), the following for prediction

```
my_predict = sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: my_data})
```

where `my_data` should be Nx4, since 4 is the number of features in the iris dataset, and N number of examples you want to classify.

Then, `my_predict` is a vector of size N containing the class of each example you provided.